# mypy "Incompatible return value type" with dict comprehension and isinstance

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy, typing, dictionary-comprehension

I have an issue with mypy giving the following error:

`Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, Pin]", expected "Union[Dict[str, Input], Dict[str, Output]]")  [return-value]mypy`

in the following example code:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Union, Type

class Pin():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Input(Pin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Output(Pin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

INPUT_STRINGS: List[str] = ["in", "input", "i"]
OUTPUT_STRINGS: List[str] = ["out", "output", "o"]

def filter_pins(pins: Dict[str, Pin], which) -> Union[Dict[str, Input], Dict[str, Output]]:
        direction: Union[Type[Output], Type[Input]]
        if which.lower() in OUTPUT_STRINGS:
            direction = Output
        elif which.lower() in INPUT_STRINGS:
            direction = Input
        filtered = {name: pin for name, pin in pins.items() if isinstance(pin, direction)}
        return filtered
```

The goal of the `filter_pins` function is to take a dict of `Pin` instances and only return either `Input` or `Output` instances in a dict. So in the dict comprehension, I'm using `isinstance` to check which subclass of `Pin`, each `pin` is.
It seems like mypy doesn't recognize that `pin` will always be either `Input` or `Output`. I think this is a case of 'type narrowing' and should in principle work.
Any ideas whether I can and should fix this or it's a mypy issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Never use built-ins names as variables names (`dir`).

Comment: @maciek97x It's okay to shadow builtin names as local variables if you know you won't be using their functionality.

Comment: @maciek97x good point. My editor didn't pick up on that. But it's not the cause of the problem here. Will update the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Input` and `Output` are both subclasses of `Pin`, would simply using `Pin` in the output type work for you?

```py
def filter_pins(pins: Dict[str, Pin], which: str) -> Dict[str, Pin]:
```

If not, here's an alternative: [cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the output to the `Union` type (note that `cast` does nothing at runtime, it is only for static type checking)

```py
return cast(Union[Dict[str, Input], Dict[str, Output]], filtered)
```

And if you can accept changing the signature of `filter_pins`:

```py
from typing import Dict, List, TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T', Input, Output)

def filter_pins(pins: Dict[str, Pin], filter_type: Type[T]) -> Dict[str, T]:
    filtered = {name: pin for name, pin in pins.items() if isinstance(pin, filter_type)}
    return filtered

class PinCollection:
    pins: Dict[str, Pin] = {}

    @property
    def inputs(self) -> Dict[str, Input]:
        """Returns only the input pins."""
        return filter_pins(self.pins, Input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think returning a`'Pin` type would work, since I have a '@property' later on which uses `filter_pin` and that should return the type `Input` (and another one with `Output`). Let me look into the `cast` option.

Comment: I added another possibility in my answer by changing the function signature. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue and is actually a more elegant way to filter the pins. Based on the actual class and not some string that I have to compare.